# set textbox text using wpf and Devexpress MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

How can i set the `Text` of a `Textbox` using wpf and Devexpress free MVVM when a button is clicked?

This is the xaml code of my Textbox

```
<TextBox Width="200" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SelectedText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="14"/>
```

this is my VM code

```
        public virtual string SelectedText { get; set; }
        void AutoUpdateCommandExecute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Code is Executing");
            SelectedText = "TextBox Text is Not Changing";
        }
```

The code is Executing but it doesn't change the `Text` of the `Textbox`

But when i type something in the `textbox` and get the text of that textbox using this code.

```
        void AutoUpdateCommandExecute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Code is Executing");
            Console.WriteLine(SelectedText);
        }
```

It prints the Text i typed in the Textbox. So what did i do wrong? I can't set the Text?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your selected text needs to be either a DependencyProperty which will then notify the binding that it's value has changed...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedText", typeof(string), typeof(YourClassType));

public string SelectedText
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedTextProperty ); }
  set { SetValue(SelectedTextProperty , value); }
}
```

OR

your VM needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and in the SelectedText setter you need to fire a property changed event...

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private string _selectedText;
  public string SelectedText
  {
    get { return _selectedText; }
    set
    {
      _selectedText = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedText");
    }
  }

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved me. i used the second one. But my question is what do is put it here? in the YourClassType  ****typeof(YourClassType)

Comment: The DependencyProperty belongs to the class it is defined in, so if the class was called ClassExample, the DependencyProperty register would have typeof(ClassExample). This tells the framework what class to find the property in.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation really helped me